# framework not found KissXML

Tags: xcode9, kissxml

I get a `framework not found KissXML` error a compile of some third party code that I did not write.  I am using XCode 9.1.

[image]

I see that KissXML does not have the suitcase icon on this screen:

[image]

Other people have reported this problem on stack, but the solutions seem very strange such as replacing code in the project from a third party site.  I suspect this is some configuration issue as this code previously compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the developer moved the KissXML framework into a different framework so all I  had to do was highlight the KissXML framework and click - to remove it from the list.